# AWS ec2 instance issues with adding awscli to instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-cloud9

After I ssh into my EC2 instance I've been trying to add AWS cli to my instance so I can send images to ECR.

My ec2 instance produces this after I enter this::

```sh
[ec2-user@ip-10-10-2-237 ~]$ curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
```

to terminal .

Return

```sh
curl: (7) Failed to connect to s3.amazonaws.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

I believe its something with my networking but im fairly new to aws and networking, so im a bit lost in this scenario.

Below is all my networking rule/settings, if anyone could provide some insight into this that would be a live saver. Thanks in advance for any help!

After this step I would grab images from my docker and send to was ECR. So this is my final step

[Networking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e16o.png)

[ACL Outbounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVu3A.png)
[ACL inbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqkbL.png)

Comment: How do you connect to the EC2 instance to run that command? If you use SSH from the Internet, then the instance would be in a public subnet. The inability to reach the Internet would therefore be due to a configuration in the Outbound rules of the Security Group associated with the instance, or the configuration of the Network ACLs associated with the subnet used by the instance. Please show those configurations in your Question.

Comment: It's a security group issue.

Comment: @Manjeet Are there any rules you recommend adding, removing or updating ? ive added and deleted many and still haven't got it to connect to internet

Comment: @JohnRotenstein ive added screenshots of the ACL's associated

Comment: I recommend that you (at least temporarily) reset the NACL rules to their default "Allow All" setting in both directions and try again. There is normally very little reason to configure NACL rules unless you are creating a DMZ. Most security can be implemented in the Security Groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network ACLs (NACLs) should generally not be modified from their default "Allow All" settings. While they represent traditional routers, they can be difficult to configure.

Instead, it is recommended to use **Security Groups**, which have several advantages over NACLs:

- They apply to each instance individually
- They can refer to other Security Groups, enabling rules that only apply between specific pairs of resources
- They are **stateful**, meaning that a permitted incoming connection can be sent a response without needing an Outbound rule to be defined

NACLs are only required if there is a specific security need, such as defining a DMZ or very tightly locking-down access. Since NACLs are **stateful**, rules must be defined in both directions. This makes them harder to configure and more likely to cause problems.

Therefore, I'd recommend keeping the NACLs at their default "Allow All" settings, and use the Security Groups to control the access.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your bucket is private? That means you will need authorization to be able to access the object in that bucket.
If you use curl, you pass the Authorization header in your curl command. I think you can use IAM access key to form your Authorization token. You can also create a presigned url for that object. With a presigned url, you don't need to pass Authorization header as it is embedded into that url.

Comment: Are you referring to the S3 bucket I created?

Comment: Ok my bad. For some reason I thought it was an authentication issue. Did not read the connection time out. Anyway, your ec2 instance must be able to reach the s3 endpoint s3.amazonaws.com. If your instance is in a private subnet, this means you need either a NAT gateway or VPC endpoint. If your instance is public, it only needs Internet Gateway although a VPC endpoint to s3 endpoint is recommended for data privacy reasons.

Comment: I believe I have a VPC endpoint and S3 endpoint swell as a NAT gateway to the vpc, not sure if I need both.